# My Function will not inject text into my HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a quiz for my web site and I would like for my function to be able to inject text into my HTML. It has worked for every other function but this one does not work. I have tried to change my injection method. I have also tried to use a JQuery method to inject my text but it still wont let me.

```js
function quiz() {
  var f = 0;
  alert(f);
  if (document.getElementById("answer1").checked == true) {
    f++;
  };
  if (document.getElementById("answer2").checked == true) {
    f++;
  };
  if (document.getElementById("answer3").checked == true) {
    f++;
  };
  if (document.getElementById("answer4").checked == true) {
    f++;
  };

  function checkpass() {
    var a = ""
    if (f == 4) {
      a = "Y"
      alert(a)
    } else {
      a = "N"
      alert(a)
    };
  };
  checkpass();
  alert(document.getElementById("score"))
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = `Score:${f}/4 ${a}`;
};
```

```html
<div id="WebBody">
  <P>Answer True or False on qustions</P>
  <p>Is ___</p>
  <form>
    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer1" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>True</label><br>   <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>False</label>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <p>Is ___</p>
  <form>
    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer2" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>True</label><br>   <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>False</label>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <p>Is ___</p>
  <form>
    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer3" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>True</label><br>   <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>False</label>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <p>Is ___</p>
  <form>
    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer4" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>True</label><br>   <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>False</label>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <button onclick="quiz()">Submit</button>
  <p id="score">Score:Not Submitted</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked for errors in your browser's console? Does any of the `alert`s show up?

Comment: variable `a` is not accessible from outside the `checkpass` function.

Comment: Use your inspector - its telling you exactly the error: `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined"`

Comment: `f` is not in scope in the second function and neither `a` nor `f` are available to your last statement. Move them outside your functions

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```js
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = `Score:${f}/4 ${a}`;
```

You are trying to access the variable "`a`" that's inside checkpass function, You need to put the variable outside from the checkpass functions.

This is your code

```js
function checkpass() {
    var a = ""
    if (f == 4) {
      a = "Y"
      alert(a)
    } else {
      a = "N"
      alert(a)
    };
  };
```

It should be something like this:

```js
var a = "";
function checkpass() {
    if (f == 4) {
      a = "Y"
      alert(a)
    } else {
      a = "N"
      alert(a)
    };
  };
```

And by the way, variable "`f`" is declared correctly it's not the problem because the error says `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined"` and variable "`a`" is after variable "`f`" So it's more like it can't access variable "`a`" not var "`f`"

Comment: Better would be for the function to `return a`

Comment: It's better but the easiest way for now is to just move the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOctyPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>


<div id="WebBody">
  <P>Answer True or False on qustions</P>
  <p>Is ___</p>
              <form>
                    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer1" name="T/F" type="radio">
                    <label>True</label><br>
                    <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">
                    <label>False</label>
              </form> 
              <hr>
  <p>Is ___</p>
              <form>
                    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer2" name="T/F" type="radio">
                    <label>True</label><br>
                    <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">
                    <label>False</label>
              </form> 
              <hr>
  <p>Is ___</p>
              <form>
                    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer3" name="T/F" type="radio">
                    <label>True</label><br>
                    <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">
                    <label>False</label>
              </form> 
              <hr>
  <p>Is ___</p>
              <form>
                    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer4" name="T/F" type="radio">
                    <label>True</label><br>
                    <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">
                    <label>False</label>
              </form> 
              <hr>
      <button onclick="quiz()">Submit</button>
  <p id="score">Score:Not Submitted</p>
</div>




<script>
function quiz() {
  var f = 0;
  var a = ""
  alert(f);
  if (document.querySelector("#answer1").checked == true){
    f++ ;
  };
  if (document.querySelector("#answer2").checked == true){
    f++ ;
  };
  if (document.querySelector("#answer3").checked == true){
    f++ ;
  };
  if (document.querySelector("#answer4").checked == true){
    f++ ;
  };
  function checkpass(){
    if (f == 4) {
      a = "Y"
      alert(a)
    } else { 
      a = "N"
      alert(a)
    };
  };
  checkpass();
  alert(document.querySelector("#score").textContent);
  document.querySelector("#score").innerHTML = `Score:${f}/4 ${a}`;
};

quiz();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just have to move the definition of `a` to outside `checkpass` or return it because it's needed in the last line (which is outside `checkpass`). (I'm showing the latter because another answer already shows the first). You might want to look into [the js debugger in devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#the_javascript_debugger), because this kind of slips are not unusual, but easy to catch with debugger.

(Also I changed your "score" element alert because alerts are not like console.log - full, expandable objects will not be displayed, just string.)

```js
function quiz() {
  var f = 0;
  alert(f);
  if (document.getElementById("answer1").checked == true) {
    f++;
  };
  if (document.getElementById("answer2").checked == true) {
    f++;
  };
  if (document.getElementById("answer3").checked == true) {
    f++;
  };
  if (document.getElementById("answer4").checked == true) {
    f++;
  };
  
  function checkpass() {
    var a = "";
    if (f == 4) {
      a = "Y"
      alert(a)
    } else {
      a = "N"
      alert(a)
    };
    return a;
  };
  var a = checkpass();
  alert(document.getElementById("score").outerHTML)
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = `Score:${f}/4 ${a}`;
};
```

```html
<div id="WebBody">
  <P>Answer True or False on qustions</P>
  <p>Is ___</p>
  <form>
    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer1" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>True</label><br>   <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>False</label>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <p>Is ___</p>
  <form>
    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer2" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>True</label><br>   <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>False</label>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <p>Is ___</p>
  <form>
    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer3" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>True</label><br>   <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>False</label>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <p>Is ___</p>
  <form>
    <input class="Radio-Button" id="answer4" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>True</label><br>   <input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F" type="radio">   <label>False</label>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <button onclick="quiz()">Submit</button>
  <p id="score">Score:Not Submitted</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the other answers explained what was wrong

Here is a version using recommended eventListener and a more elegant way of counting.
Also the HTML is simpler and if you want to submit the form, you will get the correct names

Note this quiz does not know or care how many questions there are

```js
const correct = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4"];
document.getElementById("quizForm").addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submit
  const f = [...document.querySelectorAll(".Radio-Button:checked")]
    .filter(rad => correct.includes(rad.id)).length; // count correct answers
  const a = f === correct.length ? "Y" : "N";
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = `Score:${f}/${correct.length} ${a}`;
});
```

```html
<form id="quizForm">
  <div id="WebBody">
    <P>Answer True or False on questions</P>
    <p>Is ___</p>
    <label><input class="Radio-Button" id="answer1" name="T/F1" type="radio">True</label><br>
    <label><input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F1" type="radio">False</label>
    <hr>
    <p>Is ___</p>
    <label><input class="Radio-Button" id="answer2" name="T/F2" type="radio">True</label><br>
    <label><input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F2" type="radio">False</label>
    <hr>
    <p>Is ___</p>
    <label><input class="Radio-Button" id="answer3" name="T/F3" type="radio">True</label><br>
    <label><input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F3" type="radio">False</label>
    <hr>
    <p>Is ___</p>
    <label><input class="Radio-Button" id="answer4" name="T/F4" type="radio">True</label><br>
    <label><input class="Radio-Button" name="T/F4" type="radio">False</label>
    <hr>
    <button>Submit</button>
    <p id="score">Score:Not Submitted</p>
  </div>
</form>
```